# Pandas datareader time constraints

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-datareader

Is there a way to extract data via pandas datareader for only 1 specific date?

Lets say I wanted to extract some info on for only today:

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
now = dt.datetime.now()
start = now.year, now.month, now.day
q = web.DataReader(source, 'googl', start, start)
```

However, when I run this I get all data from the earliest possible time to now.

Is there a way around this?

edit:
When implementing the commenters suggested code, I still get all possible dates from the source. my code below:

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from io import StringIO
import time    
def updatestock(stock):
        #now = dt.datetime.now()
        #start = now.year, now.month, now.day
        start_date = date = dt.datetime.now().date()
        q = web.DataReader(list_of_tickers, 'stooq', start = start_date, end = 
        start_date)
        resq = q.stack().reset_index()
        resq.columns.names = [None]
        resq.index.names = ['ID']
        stockdata = resq.groupby('Symbols')
        return stockdata

    list_of_tickers = ['DELL', 'GRPN', 'EBS']
    data = updatestock(list_of_tickers)

    stock1 = data.get_group('GRPN')
```

Comment: Can you share the current and expected output, or at least enough code and data for us to run the program? See: [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: I've found the solution. The 'stooq' api wasn't working with the start and end date. Using 'yahoo' as a source fixed it

e.g.,:

```
start = ('8-20-2019')
end = ('12-20-2019')

df = web.DataReader("AAPL", 'yahoo', start, end)
```

Comment: The question specifies data for just 1 date. start date end end date being same. This works only for today using 'yahoo' as the source. For eg, if today is 2021-06-01, and you specify start='2021-06-01', end='2021-06-01', you get only that date's data. However, if today, you are looking for specific prior date, say '2021-05-18' & provide start='2021-05-18' and end='2021-05-18', it will give data for 2 days - '2021-05-18' and '2021-05-19', provided there is trading on 2021-05-19. Essentially, you will get one day's data if next day is not a trading day, or next day is future date. A bit weird.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

`import datetime
start_date = date = datetime.datetime.now().date()
q = web.DataReader(source, 'googl', start=start_date, end=start_end)`

I tested it successfully by having "start" and "end" parameters are of type datetime.datetime or datetime.date.

Pandas data reader for "Stooq" does not have Date filters implemented. This is the reason why, the proposed code didn't work for you. So, you need to add extra code to filter the records in the returned DataFrame. You can try something like the following:

```
# Filter the Stooq Results by a Specific Date
stock_filter_mask = stock1["Date"] == start_date # Where "Date" is the column which contains date in returned DF.
stock_output = stock1[stock_filter_mask]
print("output = ", stock_output)
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I added an edit where I attempted your suggestion. Unfortunately, I cannot get it to work.

Comment: Hi Lgleather, yes referring to your edit, now you are consuming the APIs of "https://stooq.com" through "pandas_datareader". Check out my edit with the answer for this case.